# Hibernate 4 Multi-tenancy Issue - No Entity Persisters Found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have been trying to integrate hibernate 4 multi-tenancy support in our application but I get the below exception on executing an hql query

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.resultClassChecking(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:344)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy288.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:291)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.createQuery(Unknown Source)
```

The hql query is -

```
List<Field> fields = entityManager.createQuery("from " + Employee.class.getName() +
                    " where " + getQueryForInClause("id", ids), Employee.class).getResultList();
```

On debugging hibernate source, I realize that this is because hibernate's SessionFactory instance does not have any entityPersister instances due to which the hql query does have any translator's.

Is it because the Entity beans are not getting scanned? If so what could be the cause?

The entityFactory spring is declared as below

```
<property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"/>
<property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="/com/software/persistence/persistence.xml"/>
<property name="jpaProperties">
    <map>
        <entry key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"/>
        <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>
        <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="com.software.persistence.ExtendedOracle10gDialect"/>
        <entry key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="10"/>
        <entry key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data" value="true"/>
        <entry key="hibernate.jdbc.batch.builder" value="com.software.persistence.OracleBatchBuilder"/>
        <entry key="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="DATABASE"/>
        <entry key="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver"
                  value="com.software.persistence.MultitenantIdentifierResolver"/>
        <entry key="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider"
                  value-ref="multiTenantConnectionProvider" />
    </map>
</property>
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostly the error seems to be because entity beans are not getting scanned.

Can you also share persistence.xml for reference.

Following can be tried to in order to further debug (one of these step could possible solve the issue I guess)

1 Specify persistenceXmlLocation with classpath as this`<property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:/com/software/persistence/persistence.xml"/>`

2 Try with persistenceUnitPostProcessors to scan the beans some like this `<property name="persistenceUnitPostProcessors" ref="some_implementation_bean_ref"/>`